# Why is Export to Excel and CSV javascript function not working?

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel, html-table

I am trying to export an html table to excel using JavaScript. However I keep getting the following error.

```
ActiveXObject is not defined
[Break On This Error] var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
```

Here is a link to my code in JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BxV9E/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are receiving the following JavaScript error (or similar - I captured in IE9)?

> SCRIPT429: Automation server can't
>   create object

I believe you'll find that the script works fine when run locally, but not from a remote location. This is a restriction in your IE settings. Not sure what you need to change, but check for OLE Automation or some other scripting permission setting.

Comment: I am testing the script locally and it is not working in IE or firefox.

Comment: Perhaps your security settings won't allow the Ole Automation even locally. I was able to run your example successfully when running from local disk, but not when running on a remote server.

Comment: Also note that your javascript will only work in IE - no other browsers support ActiveXObject.